# Multiple one to many Relationships Mapping

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'am new to NHibernate and i have a task to enhance a project with an existinig implementation.The current design is straight forward ,as in the 'First Project':

```
store(1)->(many)Employee
```

Now i want to do this:

```
store(1)->(many)Employee  AND
Empoyee(1)->(many)Child
```

Re-implementing the mapping logic from store-Employee to Employee-Child does not work.
Tried to find s`enter code here`omething similar on the net but no luck.
Any tip about the mapping is very much appreciated.

Thanks

@MeckLey: Thanks very much 
for the response 
- I am trying to test the Mapping using the Persistent specification examples..in pseudocode iam doing something like:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<Child>(_session, new CustomEqualityComparerChild())
  .CheckProperty(c => c.Name, "Child1Name")
    --other Child prperties--
  .CheckReference(c => c.Employee, new Employee{
        Store = new Store{--store properties--},
          --other Employee Properties--
        });
```

Foreign key Columns that should not have null are inserted null values. I try to make the test so that everything is created in the right order:

```
Store->Employee->Child
```

..but i fail

@Meckley ok,here's the real thing..'store' is "ReturnOrder",'Employee' is "ReturnOrderLineItem" and 'Chlid' is "ReturnOrderReplacementItem"
The classes follow the exact structure of the "FirstExample" and the Mappings are as follows:

```
public ReturnOrderMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.OrderTrackingNumber);
        Map(x => x.UserId);

        HasMany(x => x.ReturnOrderLineItems).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }

 public ReturnOrderLineItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Sku);
        Map(x => x.Status);
        Map(x => x.Comments);

        HasMany(x => x.ReturnOrderReplacementItems).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        References(x => x.ReturnOrder);
    }

 public ReturnOrderReplacementItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Quantity);
        Map(x => x.Size);
        References(x => x.ReturnOrderLineItem);
    }
```

I'll skip the Mapping tests and try to see if it really works,maybe you can't test something like this with PesristenceSpecification..

Comment: the relationship between employee and child has nothing to do with the relationship between store and employee. That said, the mechanics of relating the employee to the child, and vice versa, are the same.

what have you tried so far that is failing?

Comment: Thanks for the response - I am trying to test the Maping using the Persistent specification examples..in pseudocode iam doing something like:

Comment: please update your original post rather than enter code into the comments.

Comment: what we need are the mappings and then NH code. `PersistenceSpecification<T>` isn't helpful as it's just an abstraction over NH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,made it work.I provide some details for anyone encounters the same task:

1)The mapping for the child within the EmployeeMap should be 
HasMany(x => x.Child).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
(WITHOUT Inverse)

2)In Child table allow NULLS for the Foreignkey field so that Deletion of a Child object is feasible

3) First save the Store object that will save the Employees attached to it and then add Child objects to an Employee's list

4)Create a seperate method for saving an Empolyee instance-similar to the method that saves a Store instance-that will in turn save all the Child objects added to the Employee's list of Child objects.